# How to "Pop-Up" a GUI on a build pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are utilizing Azure Devops (TFS) build pipeline for managing a Git Repository/branches/stages (Dev/test/prod) and one thing that came up is the concept of "cherry-picking" commits. However, the user would have to supposedly look at the commit hash code and pass it in as argument to deploy that specific commit should a use case scenario arise like that.

The project manager has asked if we can make some sort of GUI pop-up at a certain step of the build pipeline that displays the list of these commit hashes and allows a user to check the boxes for the ones they'd want to cherry-pick and deploy.

How can that be done? we are considering utilizing Java with TFS/Azure Devops API's, but not sure if we can pop-up something like that on the Azure Devops page mid-pipeline deployment.

[image: commit]

Comment: Maybe you should include also your original problem that leads into users entering commits for builds. It just sounds like something that's not right...

Comment: @JamesZ not sure i am understanding, you mean like elaborate the use case behind cherry-picking?

Comment: Yes, exactly, maybe there's a better way to solve the actual problem that leads into this

Comment: @JamesZ im gonna post some screenshots but the idea is that since TFS unfortunately does not have a drop-down list that would list commit hashes, the project manager said they dont want to deal with having to pass in hash codes manually themselves into a variable unless thats the only option, so he said explore if we can implement a GUI pop-up on the build pipeline instead of such variable. of course, we would love to explore any other options that can ease this as well, we just thought GUI would be the best option here.

Comment: The answer to your question is "No". Your process sounds really broken. I'm seconding @JamesZ here, please explain what this "cherry picking" process is accomplishing that can't be accomplished by having a proper branching/pull request/branch policy workflow.

Comment: @DanielMann I added an image to hopefully help showcase why this is a use case requirement. so the idea is sometimes theres multiple commits and latest commit on say dev branch, but deploying to test branch, lets say the user DOESNT WANT the latest commit to be deployed for that file1 but instead a prior commit.

Comment: @Cataster This is generally not managed by building up an elaborate process around cherry picking, but by having a mature branching/pull request model whereby changes are only merged into a stable branch when they are done.

Comment: It is not possible to pop up a  gui on a build pipeline. it is not interactive.

Comment: @Levi Lu-MSFT thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build pipeline is not user interactive while running. So you can not pop up a gui on a build pipeline.

If you want to check the commits and pass the commits to build pipeline to build. You can first go to the **Commits** under **Repos** and check for the commits of a branch.

[image]

Then when you queue your build pipeline. You can click the dropdown menu for **Branch/tag**, select **Commits**, and then enter the commit id you get from above step. The build pipeline will then build the commit you entered.

[image]

Comment: Yep apparently we'd have to alter the code of Azure devops itself if we want a built in UI. we opened a case with Microsoft and one of the engineers had suggested utilizing more branches for each code iteration which holds the commits, then using agent less, we can pause the build pipeline using manual intervention task